# How to use array in PHP language

Tags: php

I have this code but when I run it it give me error ( Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\test3.php on line `$str[$row['term_no']] += ",".$row['code'];` )

How can I solve this problem?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con, "uoh");
$q = " SELECT * FROM `degree_plan` LEFT JOIN courses ON
    degree_plan.course_number=courses.course_number
    where major='COE'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $q);
if ($result) {

    $str = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        {
            $str[$row['term_no']] += "," . $row['code'];
        }
        foreach ($str as $key => $value) {

            echo $value;
            echo $key;
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `If everything else failed, RTFM`....

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: I am not sure what that line is trying to do...but array_push() is probably close.

Comment: I want this code print list of courses and the courses that have the same term_no  will be grouped

Comment: FYI, there's no need to have `$str[$row['term_no']] += "," . $row['code'];` in braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are puting all codes in one element which is never defined.

change this:

```
$str[$row['term_no']] += ",".$row['code'];
```

to this:

```
$str[$row['term_no']] = $row['code'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because the array element doesn't exist, so, first check the element : if it exist, add, if it doesn't, create:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   if ( isset( $str[$row['term_no']] ) ) // IF ELEMENT EXISTS...
        $str[$row['term_no']] .= ",".$row['code']; // ADD TO ELEMENT.
   else $str[$row['term_no']] =  $row['code'];  // CREATE ELEMENT.
}
```

Comment: @JAMES, this answer allows you to accumulate all the codes under one "term_no" because it's using `.=`. If you do only `=` you will not accumulate codes, you will only have the last one.